# Giving access to Azure resources to a third party using service principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would really like your input in this guys. I tried to find documentation online but no one seems to be using this method, which makes me think it's not a good idea ... but still I want to have a conversation about it.

We need to give access to our Azure Service Bus Topic to a third party. We chose to use OAuth and Client Credentials flow since it's not going to be an interactive login, but a service app on the client side. So it means we need to create an app registration and a client secret and transmit them to the third party so they can code their part.

I was wondering why do we want to manage the identity and the secret? If we need to rotate the secret each year and transmit it to them, why not let them govern their identity and the credentials themselves since we don't really benefit from doing so. They would need to create a multi-tenant app and we would install it in our tenant (tested and working) and then they can use it to authenticate and we can give this service principal RBAC roles that it needs for its job.

THEY are in charge of the secret rotation and we managed the permissions we give the SP. No more managing and transmitting a secret on our side.

I created a multi-tenant app on my test tenant, I installed it in our tenant as an enterprise application and I was able to manage its permissions. So my test tenant was in charge of the identity (app registration and secret) and my "prod" tenant was in charge of installing the app and managing its permissions.

Comment: It is a good idea to let the third party govern their identity and credentials themselves since you don't benefit from managing it. They can create a multi-tenant app and install it in your tenant, and then use it to authenticate while you give this service principal RBAC roles that it needs for its job. This way, they are in charge of secret rotation and you manage the permissions you give the service principal.

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!